# ActiveAdmin set a form input as required for creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, user-input, activeadmin, required

I seem to be having an issue where using ActiveAdmin 2.9 and I am requiring a title for creation utilizing `input_html: {required: true}` And it is still allowing me to submit forms without a title. Is there something else I have to do for Active Admin to validate this title requirement? Below is my form for clarity.

```rb
form title: 'Notes' do |f|
 f.inputs 'Note' do  
  f.semantic_errors
  f.input :topic
  f.input :title, input_html: {required: true}
  f.input :body, as: :quill_editor
 end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: maybe you miss `:`

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo . I already had it correctly as input_html: {required: true}

Comment: Have you added the validation to the underlying model?

Comment: i guess you want to restrict a text input field, right ? if correct then let  try `required: true` without `input_html` ,  since `activeadmin` use [formtastic](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic) and it's doc show all text input cases declare `require` that way

Comment: `f.input :title, :required => true`

Comment: I ended up having to just put validations into the model to require input. I tried `required: true` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you mean the browser (html5) validation or the Rails validation. I think you mean the html5 validation since it will actually prevent the submission.
The browser html5 validation in [formtastic is opt in](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic/blob/b104bb1fe5228ea37f668917b13d0888f8bd033a/lib/generators/templates/formtastic.rb#L87), it won't work unless you turn it on.

You need to create a formtastic initializer (config/initializers/formtastic.rb) and put this in:
`Formtastic::FormBuilder.perform_browser_validations = true`

Comment: `Formtastic::FormBuilder.use_required_attribute = true` is also ok, right ? , especially for the HTML5 `required` attribute.